# Docker-compose + Django + Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm not able to get the data I fill in my models to go to my database. When I do the migrations, the project works in browser, on localhost, but when I view it inside the postgres database, nothing appears. I made my docker-compose in a way that it does the migrations itself, however, still nothing happens.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_ENGINE=${POSTGRES_ENGINE}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
  web:
    build: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_ENGINE=${POSTGRES_ENGINE}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I've tried everything, I've looked in several places, but nothing makes my migrations go to my database. Can someone help me?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly with "it works on the web" and how do you seed the environment variables?

Comment: works in browser, on localhost

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out what the problem was. I specified the port inside docker-compose and took it into my .env file and distributed to both my docker-compose and my django

follow changes in my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5001:5432
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env 
    
  web:
    build: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
```